# Add a node to existing oVirt gluster cluster

Tags: centos, centos7, ovirt

I have a working infrastructure composed with 4 physical servers :

- 1 engine (which will be self-hosted later)
- 3 nodes

I use gluster to have distributed filesystem and easy and fast VM migration.

I want to add a new node into this cluster, but I don't find a working way to do it.

Does someone has a working procedure ?

ovirt 4.3.5
CentOS 7

Answer (score 0):

First of all , I don't recommend this way of high availability , GlusterFS is not too suitable for huge files of RAW disks !
(I'd terrible experiences at three years ago)

although, you should add an ovirt node , and install required packages for gluster filesystem and then add it to your Datacenter!

please explain your issues in details to find what's wrong in your configruation